# CoffeeScript with Node.js not working with classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I've a person.coffee file that contains the following code

```
class Person 
  constructor: (@name) ->
  talk: ->
    "hello"

module.exports = Person
```

Now I am trying to use it in app.js

```
Person = require "./person"
p = new Person "Emma"
console.log p.talk
```

It prints [Function] in the console. Any idea that what is wrong

Note: I've updated the spaces.
Solution: I changed p.talk to p.talk() in app.js and its fixed now.

Comment: The indention is messed up. Have `constructor` and `talk` equally indented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like your indent is broken, your code will compile to

```
var Person;

Person = (function() {

  Person.name = 'Person';

  function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    ({
      talk: function() {
        return "hello";
      }
    });
  }

  return Person;

})();
```

while you want something like this

```
class Person 
  constructor: (@name) ->

  talk: -> "hello"
```

which will be compiled into

```
var Person;

Person = (function() {

  Person.name = 'Person';

  function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  Person.prototype.talk = function() {
    return "hello";
  };

  return Person;

})();
```

Comment: Thanks you. I modified the indentation but now its printing [Function] rather than "hello" any idea?

Comment: Okay I added () at the end of talk in app.js and its working now.